# Managing multiple setState() methods in single class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a timer when it will come to 0. It will navigate to the next Page.(Not created navigation yet). Till the timer is on user can answer the questions. The problem is I want to start the timer as the StartGame() file opens. In main.dart I have created a navigation for this on click on button. But when this page loads it automatically calls both ( in void getNum() and startTime() ) setState methods() one by one. Therefore answers (options) that I created as **buttons automatically changes without onPressed by user**. But I only want startTime() method to be called **once** as widget builds / inits. then after the getNum() method on every click of user.

How do i make these two setState() methods to be called individually without affecting each other.

```
class StartGame extends StatefulWidget {
  StartGameState createState() => StartGameState();
}

class StartGameState extends State<StartGame> {
  int no1, no2, no3, no4, inp1, inp2;
  int pos;
  int res;
  List<int> answers;
  GenerateQuestion g = new GenerateQuestion();
  void getNum() {
    answers = g.generateNum();
    pos = g.answerPosition();
    inp1 = g.generateValue();
    inp2 = g.generateValue();
    res = inp1 + inp2;
    answers.add(res);
    answers.shuffle();
    setState(() {
      no1 = answers[0];
      no2 = answers[1];
      no3 = answers[2];
      no4 = answers[3];
      print("set state 1 called");
    });
  } // void get Num ends here

  //counter timer starts from herer
  int counter = 10;
  Timer timer;
  void startTime() {
    counter = 10;
    timer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (counter > 0) {
        setState(() {
          counter--;
          print("set state 2 called");
        });
      } else {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `initState()` method, it gets only called once when the widget is built.

```
class _StartGameState extends State<StartGame> {   

  @override
   void initState() {
     startTime(); //this function only gets called once
     super.initState();
  }

//your Code...
```

Comment: I have tried this but still the startTime() gets called until the timer ends. 
I have attached print statements in both method this is the result.
I/flutter (30424): set state 1 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 2 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 1 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 2 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 1 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 2 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 1 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 2 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 1 called
I/flutter (30424): set state 2 called
...

Comment: getNum() returns 4 random integers. which are the 4 answer options in my UI. there is random addition question generated. and 4 random answers for that. if user select answer the next question is generated randomly and answers also. I want this activity to work for 30 seconds. therefore i am using timer. but the timer method startTimer() is expected to called only once then timer starts from 30 to 0. and getNum() is expected to called only when button is clicked. if I remove timer code. without timer my function is working properly. but with double setState() methods its calling automatically

Comment: I am calling getNum() in build method. and on the onpressed of buttons. in build method because it is showing first time null values. to avoid null values i am calling it on build to show values first time. then it will change on Onpressed